# SQL query Group by while using Union All

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, union-all

I am completely New to SQL queries and need help in combining some select statements together to form one single query.

I will start one query at a time:

```
select sum(DOCI) 
from    (
        select  POL.SP_NUM, sum(Q.AMT + POL.AMT) DOCI 
        from    S_ASSET POL
        ,       S_QUOTE_ITEM Q 
        where   POL.X_QUOTE_ID  =   Q.ROW_ID 
        and     POL.SP_NUM      in  ('000','111','222')
        group by POL.SP_NUM

        UNION ALL

        select  POL.SP_NUM, sum(QXM.AMT) DOCI 
        from    S_ASSET POL
        ,       S_QUOTE_ITEM Q
        ,       S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM QXM 
        where   POL.X_QUOTE_ID  =   Q.ROW_ID 
        and     Q.ROW_ID        =   QXM.PAR_ROW_ID 
        and     POL.SP_NUM      in  ('000','111','222')
        group by POL.SP_NUM
    )
```

Tables:

```
S_ASSET
X_QUOTE_ID  POL     AMT
A           000     1
B           111     1
C           222     1

S_QUOTE_ITEM
ROW_ID      AMT
A           10
B           10
C           1

S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM
PAR_ROW_ID  AMT
A           10
B           0

Expected O/P:
POL     AMT(sum)
A       21
B       11
C       2
```

Please help

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I wish to have "Select POL.SP_NUM, sum(DOCI) from (select statements) group by POL.SP_NUM"

Comment: maybe there is a better coding technique than what I have used to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sp_num, SUM(doci)
  FROM ( ...subquery... )
  GROUP BY sp_num;
```

The table name `pol` only exists inside the subquery. The outer query is selecting from the *result of the subquery,* not from any named table.